# Can I build this query using Laravel's Query Builder and if so, what would that look like? (DB::raw())

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I've put together this resulting query using Eloquent and Laravel's Query Builder (mixed) and I'd like to remove that "mixed" and build the entire query using Laravel's Query Builder.

How would the following query look like with Laravel's Query Builder?

```
SELECT id,
  name,
  clicks_count,
  conversions_count,
  Round(((100 / clicks_count) * conversions_count), 2) AS conversion_rate,
  Cast((cost_integral / clicks_count) AS UNSIGNED) AS cpc_integral,
  Cast((Ifnull(revenue_integral, 0) / clicks_count) AS UNSIGNED) AS epc_integral,
  Cast(Ifnull(revenue_integral, 0) AS signed) AS revenue_integral,
  Cast(Ifnull(cost_integral, 0) AS UNSIGNED) AS cost_integral,
  Cast((Ifnull(revenue_integral, 0) - cost_integral) AS signed) AS profit_integral,
  Round((CASE
    WHEN(Ifnull(revenue_integral, 0) = 0 AND Ifnull(cost_integral, 0) = 0) THEN 0
    WHEN(Ifnull(revenue_integral, 0) = 0 AND Ifnull(cost_integral, 0) > 0) THEN -100
    WHEN(Ifnull(revenue_integral, 0) > 0 AND Ifnull(cost_integral, 0) = 0) THEN 100
    WHEN(Ifnull(revenue_integral, 0) > 0 AND Ifnull(cost_integral, 0) > 0) THEN ((revenue_integral / cost_integral) * 100)
  END), 2) AS roi
FROM
  (SELECT device_types.*,
    (SELECT Count(clicks.id)
      FROM clicks
      WHERE device_types.id = clicks.device_type_id
        AND clicks.created_at BETWEEN "2021-07-06 00:00:00" AND "2021-07-08 23:59:59"
        AND clicks.campaign_id = 2) AS clicks_count,
    (SELECT Count(conversions.id)
      FROM conversions
      INNER JOIN clicks ON clicks.id = conversions.click_id
      WHERE device_types.id = clicks.device_type_id
        AND conversions.created_at BETWEEN "2021-07-06 00:00:00" AND "2021-07-08 23:59:59"
        AND clicks.campaign_id = 2) AS conversions_count,
    (SELECT sum(clicks.cost_integral)
      FROM clicks
      WHERE device_types.id = clicks.device_type_id
        AND clicks.created_at BETWEEN "2021-07-06 00:00:00" AND "2021-07-08 23:59:59"
        AND clicks.campaign_id = 2) AS cost_integral,
    (SELECT sum(conversions.payout_integral)
      FROM conversions
      INNER JOIN clicks ON clicks.id = conversions.click_id
      WHERE device_types.id = clicks.device_type_id
        AND conversions.created_at BETWEEN "2021-07-06 00:00:00" AND "2021-07-08 23:59:59"
        AND clicks.campaign_id = 2) AS revenue_integral
FROM device_types
INNER JOIN clicks ON clicks.device_type_id = device_types.id
WHERE clicks.campaign_id = 2
GROUP BY device_types.id) AS metrics
ORDER BY clicks_count DESC
```

Thank you for your help and time.

---

**Edit:**

One example is enough - the entire query does not need to be rebuilt. I only posted it because in the last thread someone told me to post the whole SQL command rather than just a fraction (I would have definitely shortened it otherwise).

It is important that these "Sub Selects" are not simple `DB::raw("(SELECT COUNT(clicks.id) FROM ...`. Instead, I would like to know how to build these using the Laravel Query Builder.

Comment: Can you please also [add](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68297767/edit) the `DB::raw()` code to your question?

Comment: Do you need to do the casts in the query or would you like to convert these to eloquent models and do the casts on model level?

Comment: Yes, the CAST should happen via SQL because I am returning the data as it comes from the query directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's how I would do that:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder;

$clicksCount = DB::table('clicks')
    ->whereColumn('device_types.id', 'clicks.device_type_id')
    ->whereBetween('clicks.created_at', [ "2021-07-06 00:00:00", "2021-07-08 23:59:59" ])
    ->where('clicks.campaign_id', 2)
    ->select(DB::raw('Count(clicks.id)');
$conversionsCount = DB::table('conversions')
    ->join('clicks', 'clicks.id', 'conversions.click_id')
    ->whereColumn('device_types.id', 'clicks.device_type_id')
    ->whereBetween('conversions.created_at', [ "2021-07-06 00:00:00", "2021-07-08 23:59:59" ])
    ->where('clicks.campaign_id', 2)
    ->select(DB::raw('Count(conversions.id)'));
$costIntegral = DB::table('clicks')
    ->whereColumn('device_types.id', 'clicks.device_type_id')
    ->whereBetween('clicks.created_at', [ "2021-07-06 00:00:00", "2021-07-08 23:59:59" ])
    ->where('clicks.campaign_id', 2)
    ->select(DB::raw('sum(clicks.cost_integral)'));
$revenueIntegral = DB::table('conversions')
    ->join('clicks', 'clicks.id', 'conversions.click_id')
    ->whereColumn('device_types.id', 'clicks.device_type_id')
    ->whereBetween('conversions.created_at', [ "2021-07-06 00:00:00", "2021-07-08 23:59:59" ])
    ->where('clicks.campaign_id', 2)
    ->select(DB::raw('sum(clicks.payout_integral)'));

$metrics = DB::table('device_types')
    ->join('clicks', 'clicks.device_type_id', 'device_types.id')
    ->where('clicks.campaign_id', 2)
    ->groupBy('device_types.id')
    ->select('device_types.*')
    ->selectSub($clicksCount, 'clicks_count')
    ->selectSub($conversionsCount, 'conversions_count')
    ->selectSub($costIntegral, 'cost_integral')
    ->selectSub($revenueIntegral, 'revenue_integral');

Builder::newQuery()->select(
    'id',
    'name',
    'clicks_count',
    'conversions_count'
)
->selectRaw('
  Round(((100 / clicks_count) * conversions_count), 2) AS conversion_rate,
  Cast((cost_integral / clicks_count) AS UNSIGNED) AS cpc_integral,
  Cast((Ifnull(revenue_integral, 0) / clicks_count) AS UNSIGNED) AS epc_integral,
  Cast(Ifnull(revenue_integral, 0) AS signed) AS revenue_integral,
  Cast(Ifnull(cost_integral, 0) AS UNSIGNED) AS cost_integral,
  Cast((Ifnull(revenue_integral, 0) - cost_integral) AS signed) AS profit_integral,
  Round((CASE
    WHEN(Ifnull(revenue_integral, 0) = 0 AND Ifnull(cost_integral, 0) = 0) THEN 0
    WHEN(Ifnull(revenue_integral, 0) = 0 AND Ifnull(cost_integral, 0) > 0) THEN -100
    WHEN(Ifnull(revenue_integral, 0) > 0 AND Ifnull(cost_integral, 0) = 0) THEN 100
    WHEN(Ifnull(revenue_integral, 0) > 0 AND Ifnull(cost_integral, 0) > 0) THEN ((revenue_integral / cost_integral) * 100)
  END), 2) AS roi')
->fromSub($metrics, 'metrics')
->orderByDesc('clicks_count')
```

Comment: `->select(DB::raw('sum(clicks.payout_integral)'))` was missing for `$revenueIntegral` and `->innerJoin` doesn't seem to exist, so I took `->join`. Thanks a lot for your time, it worked and I learned a lot and can use this for the future.

Comment: Thanks for the hints. I fixed my code. You're welcome. It's always intersting to find out that Laravel's query builder offers so much more than is documented.

Comment: Yes, "speed" plays a role here for me and by just giving the result back, not needing models, collections or the like, I can only thank you again for that.

Comment: Ah, I see. My pleasure.